# Can't access Pod lib dependencies inside Pod, only inside client App

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm building a swift pod `("Home")` which has an obj-c dependency `("API")` in it's subspec, which in turn has a few more obj-c dependencies in it's subspec. I have an example project written in swift `("Client")` to demo Home. I would expect to be able to import the Obj-C frameworks inside of Home, but instead they're both accessible to Client, and I get an error about no module named API found when I try and import it from Home. How can I import my dependencies inside my Home module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a workspace with pod + example app. Then, in same directory from workspace, create a `Podfile` with:

```
workspace './Home.xcworkspace'

target 'Home' do
    project 'Home/Home.xcodeproj'

    use_frameworks!

    pod 'API', :path => 'path for your obj-c dependency'
end

target 'Client' do
    project 'Example/Example.xcodeproj'

    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Home', :path => '.'
    pod 'API', :path => 'path for your obj-c dependency'
end
```

[You can seen a example where.](https://github.com/brunomacabeusbr/TvLightSegments)